# Android: Video not playing from raw folder

Tags: android, android-activity, video, video-streaming, android-videoview

I want to play a .mp4 video in a `Videoview` but its not playing. An error is generated `"Sorry! video cannot be played"`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    VideoView videoview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoview=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
        videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.snowfall));
        videoview.start();

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Please specify more details about exception.. And check if the video file is not corrupted

Comment: it isn't corrupted @nKognito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is thrown when framework isn't ready to play a video. Your `videoview.start()` is called too early. Add listener to start playin when video is ready.
Replace `videoview.start()` with this:

```
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
           videoview.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Its Working !! Thanks smile emoticon

Answer (score 0):

this code will be work...!!

```
  Uri uri= Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
    + R.raw.video);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
     videoView.requestFocus();
  videoView.start();

  //loop the video

      videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
             mp.setLooping(true);

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(binding.videoView.id)
        // Creating MediaController
        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)

        // Specify the location of the media file
        val uriPath: Uri = Uri.parse(
            "android.resource://" + packageName  + "/" + "raw/videofilename"
        )

        // Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uriPath)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.start()

    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="308dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.574"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```